# Start-Process not work in vscode remote-ssh

Tags: windows, start-process, vscode-remote-ssh

I use vscode remote-ssh to use my windows10 system.
And I use the following command for a background process.

```
Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden -FilePath "webui-user.bat"
```

Then I close my vscode. And the process keep running for 5 minutes.
Howerver, I's closed after 5 minutes.
Can Anyone suggest me a solution for a background process.